# Showing alternative images if image array is empty

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, if-statement

I have a gallery page for each user who has a profile on my site. I want the gallery to pull images from the database and use them in the appropriate places - I have this working. But when there are no images to display I want to display five blocks with an 'images coming soon' placeholder.

How can I adapt the following PHP code to show the placeholders if the foreach array is empty? At present if no images exist in the DB nothing is shown in the gallery space.

```
<?php foreach($galleryphotos as $galleryphoto): ?>
        <?php if(!empty($galleryphoto['galleryphoto_file'])){ ?>
        <div class="csmx-gallery-item csmx-isotope-item col-xs-12 col-sm-6 grid-sizer post-324 portfolio type-portfolio status-publish has-post-thumbnail hentry portfolio-category-france" id="gallery-1928">
            <figure>
                <a class="csmx-media " href="<?php echo $SITE_URL; ?>media/gallery-photos/<?php echo htmlentities($galleryphoto['galleryphoto_file'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?>" title="Sarah">
                    <img src="<?php echo $SITE_URL; ?>media/gallery-photos/<?php echo htmlentities($galleryphoto['galleryphoto_file'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?>" alt="Sarah">
                    <span class="overlay-background"></span>

                        <div class="overlay-caption">
                            <i class="fa fa-picture-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                            <!--<h3>Sarah</h3>-->
                            <!--<p>Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random...</p>-->
                        </div>
                </a>
            </figure>
        </div>
        <?php } ?>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Code including IF ELSE statement as provided by Marco;

```
<?php foreach($galleryphotos as $galleryphoto): ?>
        <?php if(!empty($galleryescortphoto['galleryphoto_file'])){ ?>
        <div class="csmx-gallery-item csmx-isotope-item col-xs-12 col-sm-6 grid-sizer post-324 portfolio type-portfolio status-publish has-post-thumbnail hentry portfolio-category-france" id="gallery-1928">
            <figure>
                <a class="csmx-media " href="<?php echo $SITE_URL; ?>media/gallery-photos/<?php echo htmlentities($galleryphoto['galleryphoto_file'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?>" title="Sarah">
                    <img src="<?php echo $SITE_URL; ?>media/gallery-photos/<?php echo htmlentities($galleryphoto['galleryphoto_file'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?>" alt="Sarah">
                    <span class="overlay-background"></span>

                        <div class="overlay-caption">
                            <i class="fa fa-picture-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                            <!--<h3>Sarah</h3>-->
                            <!--<p>Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random...</p>-->
                        </div>
                </a>
            </figure>
        </div>
        <?php } else { ?>
            <!-- Add your placeholder image -->
            <div class="csmx-gallery-item csmx-isotope-item col-xs-12 col-sm-6 grid-sizer post-324 portfolio type-portfolio status-publish has-post-thumbnail hentry portfolio-category-france" id="gallery-1928">
            <figure>
                <a class="csmx-media " href="" title="Sarah">
                    <img src="<?php echo $SITE_URL; ?>media/gallery-photos/no-photo.png" alt="Sarah">
                    <span class="overlay-background"></span>

                        <div class="overlay-caption">
                            <i class="fa fa-picture-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                            <!--<h3>Sarah</h3>-->
                            <!--<p>Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random...</p>-->
                        </div>
                </a>
            </figure>
        </div>
        <?php } ?>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Updated code with example from Kiran - this doesn't display the stored images but rather displays the placeholder, even if image values exist;

```
<?php if(empty($galleryphotos)) $galleryphotos[0]['galleryphoto_file'] = "image-not-available.jpg";
    foreach($galleryphotos as $galleryphoto): ?>
    <div class="csmx-gallery-item csmx-isotope-item col-xs-12 col-sm-6 grid-sizer post-324 portfolio type-portfolio status-publish has-post-thumbnail hentry portfolio-category-france" id="gallery-1928">
        <figure>
            <a class="csmx-media " href="<?php echo $SITE_URL; ?>media/gallery-photos/<?php echo htmlentities($galleryphoto['galleryphoto_file'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?>" title="Sarah">
                <img src="<?php echo $SITE_URL; ?>media/gallery-photos/<?php echo htmlentities($galleryphoto['galleryphoto_file'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?>" alt="Sarah">
                <span class="overlay-background"></span>

                    <div class="overlay-caption">
                        <i class="fa fa-picture-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                        <!--<h3>Sarah</h3>-->
                        <!--<p>Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random...</p>-->
                    </div>
            </a>
        </figure>
    </div>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: try if else for that

Comment: @VishnuBhadoriya thanks - I have tried an if else statement but suspect I did it wrong - I couldn't figure out how to keep the html as it was and construct the if else around it rather than echoing out what I already have in the snippet above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you wanted to show a placeholder photo when a gallery is empty. If so, then you might wanna do this:

```
<?php if(empty($galleryphotos)) $galleryphotos[0]['galleryphoto_file'] = "no-photo.png";
    foreach($galleryphotos as $galleryphoto): ?>
    <div class="csmx-gallery-item csmx-isotope-item col-xs-12 col-sm-6 grid-sizer post-324 portfolio type-portfolio status-publish has-post-thumbnail hentry portfolio-category-france" id="gallery-1928">
        <figure>
            <a class="csmx-media " href="<?php echo $SITE_URL; ?>media/gallery-photos/<?php echo htmlentities($galleryphoto['galleryphoto_file'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?>" title="Sarah">
                <img src="<?php echo $SITE_URL; ?>media/gallery-photos/<?php echo htmlentities($galleryphoto['galleryphoto_file'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?>" alt="Sarah">
                <span class="overlay-background"></span>

                    <div class="overlay-caption">
                        <i class="fa fa-picture-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                        <!--<h3>Sarah</h3>-->
                        <!--<p>Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random...</p>-->
                    </div>
            </a>
        </figure>
    </div>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Changes in above code:

1. first line checks if the $galleryphotos array is empty and if it is true, adds a placeholder to it.
2. removed if condition as it will be unnecessary
3. rest code is same as it should work.

Update #1:

The problem might be due to first if clause try changing the condition to:

```
if(count($galleryphotos)==0) $gallerypho...
```

Comment: It appears to be working so far as to show the no image placeholder but it is showing the no image placeholder on records that do have images and therefore an array that isn't empty.

Comment: I didn't get you there, would you please elaborate with an example?

Comment: Are you saying that the placeholder is showing every where?

Comment: part way I think you did, the placeholder is at least showing up but its showing for every profile - even if there are values to pull through - i've updated my Q with an example using your method.

Comment: yes - everywhere and no images are displayed even when there are results to show - i'm just getting the placeholder.

Comment: I have updated the answer. If it still doesn't work, would you please post the result of var_dump($galleryphotos) where there are other photos, so that we could analyse the problem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122725/discussion-between-kiran-and-ben).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php foreach($galleryphotos as $galleryphoto): ?>
        <?php if(!empty($galleryphoto['galleryphoto_file'])){ ?>
        <div class="csmx-gallery-item csmx-isotope-item col-xs-12 col-sm-6 grid-sizer post-324 portfolio type-portfolio status-publish has-post-thumbnail hentry portfolio-category-france" id="gallery-1928">
            <figure>
                <a class="csmx-media " href="<?php echo $SITE_URL; ?>media/gallery-photos/<?php echo htmlentities($galleryphoto['galleryphoto_file'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?>" title="Sarah">
                    <img src="<?php echo $SITE_URL; ?>media/gallery-photos/<?php echo htmlentities($galleryphoto['galleryphoto_file'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?>" alt="Sarah">
                    <span class="overlay-background"></span>

                        <div class="overlay-caption">
                            <i class="fa fa-picture-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                            <!--<h3>Sarah</h3>-->
                            <!--<p>Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random...</p>-->
                        </div>
                </a>
            </figure>
        </div>
        <?php } else { ?>
            <!-- Add your placeholder image -->
            <img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/762369348300251136/5Obhonwa.jpg" />
        <?php } ?>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: Thanks @Marco but it doesn't seem to work. I'm still getting nothing showing up.

Comment: But you need to place something there in the else statement to see the placeholder

Comment: @MarcoSantarossa I have included my code with your suggestion in it - you will see I am trying to duplicate the same same div but using a placeholder image rather than one pulled from the DB.

Comment: @Ben are you sure that image exists? remove the comments for `<h3>Sarah</h3>` for debugging so if you enter in the statement you see that tag.

Comment: @MarcoSantarossa the image definitely exists, I've just browsed to to it in browser too - it loads. The title tag isn't showing up when I uncomment it. This is what I thought I was doing wrong before - I thought there was more to the code I needed than adding in `<?php } else { ?>`.

Comment: @MarcoSantarossa it doesn't appear to be loading the section at all - the entire right section/container is empty.